# Minor changes in layout make the application to crash in Android.

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, crash, android-relativelayout

I made an application for android, and it was loading fine in the emulator and phone, and then I made some minor changes like shifting the position of text View elements in the layout with help of "Graphical Layout" editing option in Eclipse. and after that the application no longer starts, it just loads with a blank activity and in 2-3 seconds crashes. 
The layout that I am using looks like this currently (and this is the crashing state of layout):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".BMI" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/weight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/button1_text" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/bmi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/default_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:text="@string/height"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="@string/button2_text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the error message is in your LogCat

Comment: Remove `<requestFocus />`, I'm not sure why that's there.

Comment: @RandumbTune: this same layout working in my Eclipse IDE, post your error log

Comment: @EvanB Just because you don't know what it does, does not mean it is wrong. It has nothing to do with the requestFocus tag.

Comment: Did you try cleaning as I suggested?

Comment: Just clean your project. Your R.java will be regenerated. This will solve your problem if not then atleast will point out where is the problem and wont let you launch the project. Still crashes then post your logcat error.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project by going to "Project --> Clean..." then run the app again. After making changes in Eclipse to the `layout`, sometimes Eclipse doesn't "get" the changes right away so you end up with a goofy `ClassCastException`. A cleaning usually fixes this.

If this doesn't solve your problem then please post the logcat from the crash but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had several problems with Android build tool on both Eclipse and IntelliJ. Usually result in xml file doesn't get updated or shift up or down by a line or two. Usually, by rebuilding the project or restarting your IDE would fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".BMI" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="@string/weight"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/button1_text" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:ems="4"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:ems="4"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    </EditText>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/bmi"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/default_text"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:text="height"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:text="@string/button2_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```